# Disk size and space detection

Tags: amazon-ec2, unix, partition, disk-space-utilization, low-memory

i'm running a server with debian stable :

`Linux myhostname 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 8 00:01:30 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

It is running a nginx, mail server,ftp server and a mysql database.

This morning postfix complained it''s running out of space, so I double checked the free storage and it is as such

```
root@myhostname:# cat /etc/fstab 
/dev/xvda1 /     ext3    defaults 1 1
/dev/xvda2 /mnt  ext3    defaults 0 0
/dev/xvda3 swap  swap    defaults 0 0
none       /proc proc    defaults 0 0
none       /sys  sysfs   defaults 0 0


root@myhostname:# cat /etc/mtab
/dev/xvda1 / ext3 rw 0 0
tmpfs /lib/init/rw tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=0755 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
udev /dev tmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
/dev/xvdf /mnt ext4 rw 0 0
```

So "/dev/xvdf" is a big hdd (500GB) mounted on /mnt and it is where all the stuff related to the webservice is stored, "/dev/xvda1" instead is mounted in the root filesystem and it is an amazon aws standard image ami, 8GB, both of them should have enough free space but:

```
root@myhostname:# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1           1008M 1008M     0 100% /
tmpfs                 306M     0  306M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  286M   32K  286M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 306M     0  306M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdf             493G  1.1G  467G   1% /mnt

root@myhostname:# fdisk -l /dev/xvda1
Disk /dev/xvda1: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
```

I'm pretty sure that /dev/xvda is 8GB capacity but for some reason the system sees only 1GB and it is now entirely filled, any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

Try resize2fs to expand filesystem.
As it's AWS, it's good idea to snapshot instance first :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked like a charm!I'am struggling with the syntax highlighter of serverfault.com but the output of the command is:

root@myhostname:~# resize2fs /dev/xvda1
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem at /dev/xvda1 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 1
Performing an on-line resize of /dev/xvda1 to 2097152 (4k) blocks.

The filesystem on /dev/xvda1 is now 2097152 blocks long.

So the filesystem has been properly resized,i would also raccomend the tune2fs utility for those jobs.